# Providing an extension to FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

Because I have some angles, I would like to check for an angle modulus 360°:

```
    double angle = 0;
    double expectedAngle = 360;
    angle.Should().BeApproximatelyModulus360(expectedAngle, 0.01);
```

I have written an extension to the Fluent Assertions framework
following a tutorial : https://fluentassertions.com/extensibility/

```
public static class DoubleExtensions
{
  public static DoubleAssertions Should(this double d)
  {
    return new DoubleAssertions(d);
  }
}


public class DoubleAssertions : NumericAssertions<double>
{
  public DoubleAssertions(double d) : base(d)
  {
  }
  public AndConstraint<DoubleAssertions> BeApproximatelyModulus360(
      double targetValue, double precision, string because = "", params object[] becauseArgs)
  {
    Execute.Assertion
        .Given(() => Subject)
        .ForCondition(v => MathHelper.AreCloseEnoughModulus360(targetValue, (double)v, precision))
        .FailWith($"Expected value {Subject}] should be approximatively {targetValue} with {precision} modulus 360");
    return new AndConstraint<DoubleAssertions>(this);
}
```

When I use both namespaces :

```
using FluentAssertions;
using MyProjectAssertions;
```

Because I also use :

```
 aDouble.Should().BeApproximately(1, 0.001);
```

I get following compilation error :
`Ambiguous call between 'FluentAssertions.AssertionExtensions.Should(double)' and 'MyProjectAssertions.DoubleExtensions.Should(double)'`

How to change my code to extend the standard NumericAssertions (or other suitable class) to have my `BeApproximatelyModulus360` next to the standard `BeApproximately` ?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `using...` statement for one of namespaces or call the method directly `MyProjectAssertions.DoubleExtensions.Should(yourDouble)`

Comment: Of course ! You're right. But I expected a shorter way to write. Because it makes my call like  FluentAssertions.DoubleExtensions.Should(luminanceComputation.Beta).BeApproximatelyModulus360(0,0.01); - to be compared to :  Assert.True(MathHelper.AreCloseEnoughModulus360(0, luminanceComputation.Beta,0.01)); - that is no more very Fluent.

Comment: And actually there are some other naming conflicts that I am just experiencing that prevents using my new assertion Api the standard FluentAssertion one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to directly access the extension method on a `double` object, and not on a `DoubleAssertion` object, why introduce the complexity of even creating a new type `DoubleAssertion`. Instead, define an extension method directly for `NumericAssertions<double>`.

```
  public static class DoubleAssertionsExtensions
    {
        public static AndConstraint<NumericAssertions<double>> BeApproximatelyModulus360(this NumericAssertions<double> parent,
            double targetValue, double precision, string because = "", params object[] becauseArgs)
        {
            Execute.Assertion
                .Given(() => parent.Subject)
                .ForCondition(v => MathHelper.AreCloseEnoughModulus360(targetValue, (double)v, precision))
                .FailWith(
                    $"Expected value {parent.Subject}] should be approximatively {targetValue} with {precision} modulus 360");
            return new AndConstraint<NumericAssertions<double>>(parent);
        }
    }
```

And then you can use them together.

```
 public class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            double aDouble = 4;

            aDouble.Should().BeApproximately(1, 0.001);
            aDouble.Should().BeApproximatelyModulus360(0, 0.1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Marshal, you helped me find clarity that I lost